# ejecutar instruccion java guardada en un String

Tags: java

Como puedo ejecutar una instrucción java que esta almacenada en un String?
Aquí les dejo el código del botón en si lo que hace es cortar la cadena que se escribe en un JTextField separado por espacios que en si es para seleccionar los asientos y cambiar la imagen del asiento a ocupado para preguntar si es o son los asientos deseados aquí les dejo el código del botón

```
 private void btn_aceptarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
if(!txt_ascientos.getText().isEmpty() && !txt_pasajero.getText().isEmpty()){
String seleccion = txt_ascientos.getText();
String[] parts = seleccion.split(" ");
for(int i=0;i<parts.length;i++){
    try {
        String num =String.valueOf(i);
        num = parts[i];
        
        String cadena = "ventaBoletos.asciento"+num+".setIcon(new ImageIcon("+"\""+"src/imagenes/seleccion"+""+num+".png"+"\""+"));";
        System.out.println(cadena);
        //ventaBoletos.asciento1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/imagenes/seleccion1.png"));
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java",cadena);
        File ruta = new File(".\\build\\classes");
        pb.directory(ruta);
        Process p = pb.start();
        int valor = Integer.parseInt(num);
        if(valor>=46){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Asciento Incorrecto");
        }   } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ascientos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
}else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Datos en Blanco");
}

    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Java es un lenguaje compilado.. no se pueden ejecutar instrucciones que estan dentro de una cadena.. salvo que las mandes a compilar y las ejecutes despues... tal vez quieras explicar que tratas de hacer para poder ayudarte mejor?

Comment: No parece nada que no puedas hacer haciendo que "asciento" sea un array o un *List*.

Comment: ya lo solucione con un switch  case de la siguiente forma

Answer (score 1):

```
public void seleccionaAsiento(int num){
switch (num){
        case 1:  ventaBoletos.asciento1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/imagenes/seleccion1.png"));
                 break;
        case 2:  ventaBoletos.asciento2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/imagenes/seleccion2.png"));
                 break;
        case 3:  ventaBoletos.asciento3.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/imagenes/seleccion3.png"));
                 break;
        case 4:  ventaBoletos.asciento4.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/imagenes/seleccion4.png"));
                 break;
```

}
}